# How can I make a SpecFlow plugin that uses custom TestFixture and Test attributes?

Tags: specflow

I'm working with a team that has developed its own custom testing framework, similar to NUnit but with various added features.  I'm trying to incorporate [SpecFlow](http://specflow.org/) into our testing.  To generate the code-behind feature files with our custom TestFixture and Test attributes, I need to create a plugin.

I've created the plugin, but I'm at my wits' end trying to get SpecFlow to actually *see* it.  I've tried various permutations of the `path` setting in my App.config for the project using the plugin, even a fully-specified path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="specFlow"
    type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
 </configSections>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
      publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
 <specFlow>
  <plugins>
   <add name="SpecFlowAdapters"
     path="C:\Development\[OurProductName]\Plugins\SpecFlowAdapters.SpecFlowPlugin.dll"
     type="Generator" />
  </plugins>
 </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

But every time I regenerate the feature code, I get

```
#error Generation error: Unable to find plugin in the plugin search path:
  SpecFlowAdapters. Please check http://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details.
```

Is there anyone who's been able to successfully create a custom SpecFlow generator who can point me at sample working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in the plugins configuration should be the path to the folder where the plugin dll is located, not the full path to the assembly.

See http://specflow.org/documentation/Plugins/ at the end under *Configuration Details*